# I want to change my VIT from single-label multi-class classification to multi-label. How should I rewrite the evaluation and loss sections?

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function, vision-transformer

The new labels look like: [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0].
The original loss function: `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()`
The calculation segment：
`pred = model(images.to(device)) loss = loss_function(pred, labels.to(device))`
(How to use torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss to replace that?

I have gotten some answers from GPTs and Google without executable details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your labels in that format already, you can just swap the loss function.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

loss_fn = nn. BCEWithLogitsLoss()

logits = torch.randn(3)
labels = torch.tensor([1, 0, 1]).float()

loss = loss_fn(logits, labels)
```